# What is the practical use of panchromatic band in remote sensing?

Tags: multi-band

In Landsat and other satellite imagery, panchromatic band is also included (which normally has high spatial resolution). I want to know what is the practical use of a panchromatic image? Is it a must with other bands for LULC mapping or is it just an optional band?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the panchromatic band is, like you said, to provide an image with a high spatial resolution (compared to the units' multispectral bands).

Practically speaking, the panchromatic band can be used to [pan-sharpen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansharpened_image) a collection of images, which results in a single higher-resolution color image. From the link:

```
Low-res color bands + High-res grayscale band = Hi-res color image
```

It is not "a must" for land-use/land cover mapping. It can, however, often be practically beneficial. It's important to note that pan-sharpening can introduce spectral distortion, which may lead to classification issues.

Comment: Can PAN be used in place of other bands for LULC mapping?

Comment: It's probably more appropriate to state that the panchromatic band can be used "in addition to" other bands, not necessarily "in place of".